# .net core .XLSX streaming on AWS Lambda

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, .net-core, aws-lambda

very simply, I'm using AWS Lambda and generating .xlsx files and copying them to S3 directly from lambda, as there is a limit on memory allocation in lambda I need to move to a streaming solution when generating the xlsx file... I can already stream to S3 but this functionality is mute as the generation of the file is not using streaming...

Design:

lambda AWS:
SQL server  ->  dapper (streaming)  ->  generate xlsx  -> copy to S3 (streaming)

as you can see the xlsx part is the bottleneck here in terms of memory usage.

If you know of a library than can support this (keep in mind .net core) please let me know!

PS we cannot use node.js and I know there are options in node that do this...

thanks!

Comment: which library are you currently using ? Which functionality of xlsx do you need ? (some libs could fit your case, but can't create advanced features in the xlsx for instance)

Comment: currently EPPlus - not sure how relevant that is as if it supported streaming I would not be asking the question - just saying... ;)

Comment: We don't know if you might have missed some option of the library you are using; and I would say a great majority of questions in Stack Overflow I can see are like that. Secondly, libraries for xlsx vary greatly in their capabilities, and knowing the one you use helps set some standard on what you might be wanting, in case you didn't answer the second question I asked, which you actually didn't ;).

Comment: You can check [NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/) or [ClosedXML](https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml)

Comment: @Pac0 I have pinged both maintainers of npoi and closed xml and referenced this question. Going out on a limb Im assuming no one has done this on .net yet and there are examples on java and node. We went with EPPlus as it was the most efficient .net library we could find of generating xlsx files. I did look at the format specs and might endup writing my own but would rather not if possible...

Comment: again, I can't guess what are the features from the (very vast) xlsx specifications that you need. But both NPOI and ClosedXML allow the output to be a `System.IO.Stream`

Comment: EPPlus can save to a stream, saving to a stream and generating the file to a stream are two different things... saving to a stream at this point the whole doc is in memory, generating the file in a streaming fashion is my requirement which means chunking the file while its been generated.